# Does this code cause a retain cycle?

Tags: objective-c

I have a question, can this line cause any trouble?

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

assuming both properties of `self` have a `retain` setter:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIViewcontroller viewController;
```

my question is does this cause any weird object trees or retain cycles or memory problems? `viewController` has a retain count of `2` so if `self` wants to get rid of the memory, it can´t because the `self.window.rootViewController` still holds a reference to it? Or am I completely wrong?

[image]

Comment: just look at the arrows' direction. That doesn't look like a circle, does it?

Comment: This is perfectly safe.

Comment: retain? Pardon are you developing for iOS 4.0?

Comment: even in `ARC` you still can configure your `@property` to `retain` an object if its setter is called. I see you probably mean it should be `strong`, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deallocate `self.viewController` you would need to clear both references:

```
self.window.rootViewController = nil; // or some other controller
self.viewController = nil; // or some other controller
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just look at the direction of the arrows, you can see that there's no cycle here. The view controller will simply have two owners.